# How to parse a list of lists?

Tags: ocaml

I'm new to functional programming and Ocaml and I'm trying to write a function that when given a list of lists, check each list whose size length is equal to the rest of the lists and return true else false.

For examples:

```
[[5;2;4];[1;3]] -> false
[[1;2];[1;3]] -> true
```

So my first question, to start solving my problem, is how do you parse a list of lists?

Attempt:

```
let rec check_if_equal list = match list with
    [[h]] -> true
    |[h]::rest -> let find_len list_len = match list_len with
       [[]] -> 0
       |_::t -> 1 + find_len t
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem statement is a little unclear. I'll assume you're being asked to determine whether all the sublists are the same length. Return true if they are, false if not.

I'm also not sure what you mean by "parse". Most likely you're talking about the pattern matching part. The best way to start is to forget about the type of the elements and just think of your input as a list.

So your outermost function might look something like this if you follow your example code:

```
let rec check_if_all_same_length lists =
    match lists with
    | [] -> true (* Vacuously true *)
    | _ :: [] -> true (* One list is same length as itself *)
    | h1 :: h2 :: t -> (* Two or more lists is the hard part *)
```

Your code for calculating the length of a list looks pretty good. But note that these are the sublists of the original list. So they aren't necessarily lists of lists, they're just lists. So you should be matching against `[]` for the end of the list. Also you should declare it as a recursive function.

Note that nobody is calling the `find_len` function. That might be the next thing to work on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use List.length

```
   let rec check_if_equal = function
      | [] | _::[]  -> true
      | h1::h2::[]  -> List.length h1=List.length h2
      | h1::h2::tl  -> check_if_equal (h1::[h2]) && check_if_equal (h2::tl)
    ;;
```

Test :

```
# check_if_equal [[5;2;4]];;
- : bool = true
# check_if_equal [[5;2;4];[1;3;6];[4]];;
- : bool = false
# check_if_equal [[1;2];[1;3]];;
- : bool = true
```

Comment: (It doesn't help people in the big picture to do their homework for them.)